# Add image and allows edit

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Hi I am very new in JQUERY. It is a new thing to me.

I was tasked to be able to collect and place and Image into an area where the user is allowed to actually move the object to any position he/she prefers.

At the current point I am at, I'm not sure how to actually create a JQUERY that once click on the image, it will appear on the area where user can move the picture.

Would really appreciate help here as i'm really new to this.

The link for somethinng similar would be like as follow

**[Example](http://catifier.com/)**

Like catifier, images will be placed at the side. Once click on an image, the image will be brought to the black box and from there user can move the image around.

Comment: you *something similar* link is inoperable... does not give any idea of that's all that actually for...

Comment: As I'm new to this. I am not sure how to begin the project. I would hope that someone can help me start this off as I'm really new to this. :/

Comment: The link is **EXAMPLE** Like the link above, my images will be at the side and once clicked I was hoping Jquery would be able to place the click image into the box beside the images for a start.

Answer (score 0):

***[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/pesaqo/3/edit?html,css,js,output)***

Using **jQuery** and **jQuery UI** is easy as that:

```
<div id="thumbs">
  <img src="cat1.jpg">
  <img src="cat2.jpg">
</div>  
<div id="dropper"></div>
```

css:

```
#thumbs{float:left;width:170px;}
#dropper{background:#223;height:400px;overflow:hidden;}
```

jQuery/UI:

```
$(function(){ // DOM ready 

  $('#thumbs img').draggable({
    revert: "invalid",  // revert to original pos. if not dropped into droppable
    containment: "body" // prevent the user from dragging the image out of sight
  });
  $('#dropper').droppable(); // The droppable element

});
```

For more info see:
http://jqueryui.com/draggable/ and http://jqueryui.com/droppable/

Comment: Thank you soo much for the information. It has given me somewhat of the how the project should look in code form. You have been a great help :)

Comment: @FaizEverywhere some tips (all discoverable here on SO) I can suggest are: while you click an image make it higher `z-index` so that will overlap other images. Also you can create a method that can reset the image into `#thumbs` if dragged outside the `#dropper`. I'll leave that to your research. You know now from where to start ;)